# Eloquent query returns wrong data when when using union

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have in my code a union between public data and user specific data. What I want to achieve is that if there is no user logged in, I return data which public is true. In case that I have a user, I make another query where user_id is the logged in user. Everything works until I want to get a specific data id of a user that I shouldn't be allowed.

For example I have the data:

```
[
   'id' => 1,
   'user_id' => 1,
   'public' => true,
],
[
   'id' => 2,
   'user_id' => 1,
   'public' => false,
],
```

My current code:

```
    public function getQuery() : Builder
    {
      $publicData = $this->model->where('public', true);

      // $this->user is passed thought another method which is $request->user() result. 
      if (!isset($this->user)) {
        return $publicData;
      }

      if ($this->user->isAdmin()) {
        return $this->model->newQuery();
      }

      return $this->model
        ->where('user_id', $this->user->id)
        ->union($publicData);
    }
```

Now we assume that $this->user->id is 10 and I try to fetch data that I am not allowed by id.

```
    $data = $this->getQuery()
        ->where('id', 2)
        ->first();
```

In this situation, always the first public data, which in this case is id 1 will be returned and I expect to receive null.

I am not sure how to find a solution for this and I am not sure what am I missing. Currently I use Laravel 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Potential problem in your code, it is using one query for union and result query.

You can try check this:

```
public function getQuery() : Builder
{
  // HERE ADDED newQuery
  $publicData = $this->model->newQuery()->where('public', true);

  // $this->user is passed thought another method which is $request->user() result. 
  if (!isset($this->user)) {
    return $publicData;
  }

  if ($this->user->isAdmin()) {
    return $this->model->newQuery();
  }

  return $this->model
    ->where('user_id', $this->user->id)
    ->union($publicData);
}
```

But you recommend simplify your query, without using union, because union is unnecessary here, to example:

```
public function getQuery() : Builder
{
  $query = $this->model->newQuery();

  if ($this->user->isAdmin()) {
    return $query;
  }

  return $query->where(function ($builder) {
    $builder->where('public', true);

    if (isset($this->user)) {
       $builder->orWhere('user_id', $this->user->id);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: The second example helped me the best, I was not smart enough to think it without using union. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel you get the logged in user id by `auth()->id()`. It seems you are trying to filter the results by the eloquents’ attached users, which will obviously return `true` for every row.

Comment: Maybe I have expressed myself wrong, sorry about that. I have an abstraction but $this->user in my case is the user passed from $request->auth() which is the same as auth().